# Boolean getters autocompletion not working in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, getter, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-luna

Found that boolean getters are not autocomplete in Eclipse Luna:

[image]

The same in Kepler:

[image]

Is this a bug or by-design behavior?

Comment: You should ask it at eclipse.org.

Comment: @Jens my question is about `software tools commonly used by programmers`, so it is on-topic here, please see the rules: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic